# Sorting Values of Set

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to sort elements of a set but unable to do so far.
here is my code which i am trying to do

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Set<String> set=new HashSet<String>();
    set.add("12");
    set.add("15");
    set.add("5");
    List<String> list=asSortedList(set);
}

public static
<T extends Comparable<? super T>> List<T> asSortedList(Collection<T> c) {
  List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(c);
  Collections.sort(list);
  return list;
}
```

but this or other way is not working since its all time giving me the same order in which they have been filled
12,15,5

Comment: A `Map` is not a `Set`. BIG difference!

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't use a SortedSet if you want a sorted set?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you sort the strings `"12"`, `"15"` and `"5"` then `"5"` comes last because `"5"` > `"1"`. i.e. the natural ordering of Strings doesn't work the way you expect.

If you want to store strings in your list but sort them numerically then you will need to use a comparator that handles this. e.g.

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Integer i1 = Integer.parseInt(o1);
        Integer i2 = Integer.parseInt(o2);
        return (i1 > i2 ? -1 : (i1 == i2 ? 0 : 1));
    }
});
```

Also, I think you are getting slightly mixed up between `Collection` types. A `HashSet` and a `HashMap` are different things.

Comment: +1 ... although: Subtracting one int from another during comparison could lead to underflow; an explicit comparison would be safer.

Comment: `o1 == o2` may lead to unexpected results with non-interned Strings. Use `o1.equals(o2)` (you could also do `o1.intern()==o2.intern()` but that's awful)

Comment: Thanks @seanizer - I didn't actually mean to be comparing the Strings. I lost the calls to `parseInt` in the edit. I've revised it again.

Comment: Couldn't your return statement be reduced to `return i1.compareTo(i2);`?

Answer (score 69):

Use a SortedSet (TreeSet is the default one):

```
SortedSet<String> set=new TreeSet<String>();
set.add("12");
set.add("15");
set.add("5");
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(set);
```

No extra sorting code needed.

Oh, I see you want a different sort order. Supply a Comparator to the TreeSet:

```
new TreeSet<String>(Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf));
```

Now your TreeSet will sort Strings in numeric order (which implies that it will throw exceptions if you supply non-numeric strings)

**Reference:**

- Java Tutorial ([Collections Trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections)):

  - [Object Ordering](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
  - [The `SortedSet` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-set.html)
- Javadocs: [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)
- Javadocs: [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Comment: You can also pass that `Comparator` to the constructor of `TreeSet`

Answer (score 7):

You're using the default comparator to sort a `Set<String>`. In this case, that means [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). Lexicographically, `"12"` comes before `"15"`, comes before `"5"`.

Either use a `Set<Integer>`:

```
Set<Integer> set=new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(12);
set.add(15);
set.add(5);
```

Or use a different comparator:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return Integer.parseInt(a) - Integer.parseInt(b);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Integer` wrapper class instead of String because it is doing the hard work for you by implementing `Comparable<Integer>`. Then `java.util.Collections.sort(list);` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

[Strings are sorted lexicographically](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).  The behavior you're seeing is correct.

Define [your own comparator to sort the strings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) however you prefer.

It would also work the way you're expecting (5 as the first element) if you changed your collections to Integer instead of using String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a Comparator instance to the sort method otherwise the elements will be sorted in their natural order.

For more information check [Collections.sort(List, Comparator)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%2C%20java.util.Comparator%29)