# how to sort Set<T> in java

Tags: java, oop, set

I have Object called Book with String author , title.
I use Collection of Books (Collection) and want to print a list of all books , but in alphabetically order of author and when I have 2 or more books from one author than alphabetically order of title . How can I make this?

Comment: take a look at the TreeSet

Comment: Write some code and show us. We'll help you debug it.

Comment: Does `Book` implement `Comparable<Book>`?

Comment: I have Collection<Book> and want to make string with all the book.toString() . I tried to add them in a new TreeSet but it doesnt work.
here is my code :
public String toString(){
  String str = "";
  if(books.size()==0) return "Empty Library";
  else {
   
   Set<Book> print = new TreeSet<Book>();
   for(Book a : books){
    print.add(a);
   }
   for(Book b : print){
    str += b.toString() +"\n";
   }
  }
  return str;
 }

Comment: @nicomp can you help

Answer (score 1):

To sort T, it needs to extend from Comparable.This is:`T extends Comparable<T>`.

Then, implement the `compareTo` method and then you may be able to compare the items for the sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [sortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html). You may check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165832/sorting-values-of-set) for help.

Comment: I have Collection<Book> and want to make string with all the book.toString() . I tried to add them in a new TreeSet but it doesnt work. here is my code : public String toString(){ String str = ""; if(books.size()==0) return "Empty Library"; else { Set<Book> print = new TreeSet<Book>(); for(Book a : books){ print.add(a); } for(Book b : print){ str += b.toString() +"\n"; } } return str; }